# Java listening on multiple server ports for client attempt to connect

Tags: java, connection, serversocket, asyncsocket

OK.  I feel dumb.  I cannot find what I'm looking for.

I am opening 50 ServerSockets and adding them to a List of ServerSockets:

```
 ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(getPortNumber());
 SOCKETS.add(ss);
```

I get that I need a new thread for each connection:

```
new Thread() {
public void run() {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(getPortNumber());
    while(true) {
        Socket client = ss.accept();
        //handle client
    }
}.start();
```

So, my question is, "Do I have to use a while loop until I get a connection?"

I mean, is there a way to listen for an attempt to connect before using the ss.accept to assign Socket client?

Comment: Why? Why not only one listening socket? Why waste resources?

Comment: Because we are trying to process a cluster service.  We have massive amounts of data coming from many sensors.  I don't want to use any processing time when no sensors are trying to connect.  If new ServerSocket opens a port for listening then why can't I just listen for the "knock-knock" before trying to accept?

Comment: Using fifty sockets doesn't solve anything there. And `accept()` *is* 'listen[ing] for the knock-knock', and it doesn't 'use any processing time when no sensors are trying to connect'. It blocks. I don't understand what you're trying to solve here. Are you perhaps looking for a non-blocking server with NIO and `select()`?

Comment: I'm learning here.  The server is a system on chip.  We have very vague requirements but there could be any number of sensors trying to connect to the mobile server.  Also very rapidly sending updated data.  Lots of traffic.  It's already been suggested that we use a pool of connections.  When a sensor makes a connection, I need to queue the data.  I could use one socket for the prototype but solving this problem is a challenge for me.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unless your specification calls for fifty sockets, which it won't, use one. Write your loop exactly as above. Get it working. If you then have a performance problem, which isn't likely, you can then consider NIO, which is ten times the work. Using a pool of connections at the server doesn't really mean anything, except that each connection should be maintained until EOS is read from it. Connection pooling gets implemented at the client end. I suggest some hard work on your requirement is in order, starting with the specifications of the hardware. And no more guesswork about how sockets work.

Comment: I suggest you both read the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: NB What you have above is a new thread *per `ServerSocket`.* You only need one of those, as you only need one `ServerSocket`, but you need to create a new thread *per* accepted `Socket`, *inside* that loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We decided that (in our case) it is best to have a dedicated server socket for each client.  Therefore, I am following the answer to this SO question:

[Server Listening on Multiple Ports [Java]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5021812/1735836)

Comment: That can only work if you can so reconfigure the sensors, which wasn't stated in the question, or comments.

Comment: I did tell you about the sensors, which is the only way you could have known they were the clients.  I gave you the upvote because your information was helpful.  However, I find myself a little miffed at your arrogance.  Your way is not the only way and you should be open to alternatives.  I do not believe the downvote was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to use a while loop until I get a connection?

It depends. If you're only expecting one connection you don't need a while loop: otherwise, you do.

> I mean, is there a way to listen for an attempt to connect before using the ss.accept to assign Socket client?

The question doesn't make sense. That's what `accept()` *does.*

NB creating the `ServerSocket` already puts the port into listening state that can be connected to. But it is `accept()` that accepts connections, and nothing else.

The fact that you're creating 50 listening ports already indicates a severe design problem. You only need one. Don't waste system resources.

This all sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: You're right.  That's what accept() does.  But listening for more than one connection, I need to use the while loop for each ServerSocket.  It just seems like there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Better way why? How? What's the problem with this way?

Comment: I just read about the accept method in the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.  "The accept method waits until a client starts up and requests a connection on the host and port of this server."  That cleared up a little confusion!  I pulled the number 50 just for an example.  But now I know that if I need a connection pool then I can create a Connection class that handles the accept method on a new thread for each new connection and the open / close as needed.  Thanks!

Comment: I do seriously suggest you stop guessing. What you have just described is a standard server-side architecture for handling concurrent clients. It doesn't have anything whatsoever to do with connection *pooling.* Connection pooling is a *client-side* technique for conserving connections *from each client,* and it is used e.g. by database and LDAP clients, and web browers. All you need to do about connection-pooling at the server end is keep reading from an accepted connection until the client closes it, rather than assume there is only one request/response pair coming from it.